# можно ли зашифровать а затем расшифровать данные на php?

Tags: php, безопасность, шифрование, хеширование

смотрел урок по шифрованию и расшифровке данных с помощью mcrypt_module_open, но оказывается он устарел и не рекомендован к использованию .Есть ли альтернатива и где можно почитать или посмотреть плиз.

Comment: http://php.net/openssl

Comment: смотря что шифровать, если пароль то password_hash и обратно password_verify например, а вообще вы можете сами придумать себе шифратор и дешифратор, который будет работать с помощью какой-то логики, но нужно прочитать вам об этом больше, чтобы знать как лучше это сделать. Альтирнатива, посмотрите например PHP-JWT класс. А ещё, шифрование и хэширование - разные вещи!